# batch: command prompt works but neither file.cmd nor file.bat

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am new to batch. I work with website, I have a folder called web, in this folder, I have many sub directories, such as 'template1', 'template2', etc. In those templates, there is one thing in common, each only contains three same files, 'draw.html', 'draw.js', 'draw.css'. Each time I want to create a new page I need to manually create this pattern. I wonder if I can code a batch file, so I can do this by click on pat.bat, and it generate the folder and three files for me. after thinking, I decide to do this: in web folder, create two files: ['pat.bat', 'pat.txt'] in 'pat.txt', there are three strings seperated by line: [draw.html, draw.js, draw.css], the logic in batch file is pretty simple: it asks the user to input a directory name, then generate

```
directory_name
           |-draw.js
           |-draw.html
           |-draw.css
```

here's the batch file I worked out `<pat.bat>`

```
@echo off
:dir_loop
    echo Create a directory named: 
    set /p directory=
    if "%directory%" equ "" (
        echo Please enter a valid directory
        goto :dir_loop
        )


:pat_loop
    if not exist pat.txt (
        echo Please create a pat.txt file which
        echo contains all your files separated by 
        echo line with correct extension to 
        echo generate into the folder. 
        echo "Have you done it? (y/n)"
        set /p good=
        if not exist pat.txt (
            echo Sorry, no pat.txt detected in current directory
            goto :pat_loop
        ) 
    )


:final
    mkdir %directory%
    for /F "delims=," %i in (pat.txt) do (
        cd %directory%
        cd. > %i
        cd..
    )
```

pat.txt

```
draw.js
draw.css
draw.html
```

ok, here comes the problem, when I change the 'directory' variable to a default value rather than user input, and run this in the elevated command prompt inside my web directory, it works fine (following code)

```
@echo off
    :dir_loop
        echo Create a directory named: 
        rem !!! change directory from user input to assignment
        set directory=template1
        if "%directory%" equ "" (
            echo Please enter a valid directory
            goto :dir_loop
            )


    :pat_loop
        if not exist pat.txt (
            echo Please create a pat.txt file which
            echo contains all your files separated by 
            echo line with correct extension to 
            echo generate into the folder. 
            echo "Have you done it? (y/n)"
            set /p good=
            if not exist pat.txt (
                echo Sorry, no pat.txt detected in current directory
                goto :pat_loop
            ) 
        )


    :final
        mkdir %directory%
        for /F "delims=," %i in (pat.txt) do (
            cd %directory%
            cd. > %i
            cd..
        )
```

but, if I set the variable 'directory' to user input rather than string, when I click on the `<pat.bat>` file, entry my folder name for example, ak, it creates an ak folder in web with nothing in it. (first `<pat.bat>` code)

I guess it's my for loop's variable assignment issue, I will be so glad if you can help.

PS: you can test the code by simply create a folder on desktop, create two files inside of it pat.txt, pat.bat and paste it in. to test the second bat file, type cmd in the folder, paste in the code (make sure pat.txt is created at first)

Comment: A `for` loop variable at command prompt needs 1 percent sign and batch-file needs 2 percent signs. Change `%i` to `%%i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bat
@echo off
cd %~dp0
:dir_loop
    echo Create a directory named: 
    set /p directory=
    if "%directory%" equ "" (
        echo Please enter a valid directory
        goto :dir_loop
        )


:pat_loop
    if not exist pat.txt (
        echo Please create a pat.txt file which
        echo contains all your files separated by 
        echo line with correct extension to 
        echo generate into the folder. 
        echo "Have you done it? (y/n)"
        set /p good=
        if not exist pat.txt (
            echo Sorry, no pat.txt detected in current directory
            goto :pat_loop
        ) 
    )


:final
    mkdir %directory%
    for /F "delims=," %%i in (pat.txt) do (
        cd %directory%
        cd. > %%i
        cd..
    )
```

This code worked for me in a folder in the path `C:\Users\Neko\Desktop\Test`. There were several issues with your code.

1. As @Mofi said, in batch files, the command extension of `for` loop variables get expanded to `%%var` instead of `%var` so you have to change your `%i`s to `%%i`.
2. This code would automatically execute in the %HOMEPATH% directory (`C:\Users\<User>`) which would cause errors in finding `pat.txt`, I changed it so that it executes in the parent directory of `pat.bat`, `%~dp0` (parent directory of batch file). This would look for `pat.txt` in the same folder as the batch file (which for me was `C:\Users\Neko\Desktop\Test`) and then makes the folder in that directory. (you can change it by editing the `:final` label to include a `cd <path you want folders in>`
3. Again, like @Mofi said, `%%i` instead of `%i` is needed in batch-files. Your error was caused by this since the for loop wouldn't execute.

I ran this file with the circumstances you suggested (*you can test the code by simply create a folder on desktop, create two files inside of it pat.txt, pat.bat and paste it in. to test the second bat file, type cmd in the folder, paste in the code (make sure pat.txt is created at first)*) and it worked for me, it created `draw.js`, `draw.css`, and `draw.html` in the `C:\Users\Neko\Desktop\Test\<%directory%>` folder succesfully. (When %directory% is abc it creates `draw.js`, `draw.css`, and `draw.html` in the `C:\Users\Neko\Desktop\Test\abc` folder)